# SerializeJSON and DeserializeJSON not working properly for cfcatch block

Tags: serialization, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have a requirement for storing all the ColdFusion exception details in a database table. So I am planning to serialize the cfcatch structure and store it in db, but I have an issue.The structure before and after the serialization is not the same. So for testing purpose, here is small snippet of code I tried on my local,

```
<cftry>
 <cfset a = 5/0>
 <cfcatch type="any">
     <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
     <cfset a = SerializeJSON(cfcatch)>
     <cfdump var = "#DeserializeJSON(a)#">
 </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Here is the screenshot from the first dump (Original cfcatch).
[image]
Here is the screenshot from the second dump(i.e serialize and then deserialize)

[image]

Comment: Try `<cfset a = SerializeJSON(duplicate(cfcatch))>` - be aware that duplicate does a deep copy though.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWhish , Its working, Why do we need duplicate function here?

Comment: The cfcatch variable isn't really a ColdFusion struct, the duplicate forces it to a ColdFusion struct which it can then serialize.

Comment: @user3714162 Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618537/type-of-cfcatch-in-coldfusion) for `cfcatch` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Entered as a comment on the OP question, but adding here as well in case it's useful to others.*

Try:

```
 <cfset a = SerializeJSON(duplicate(cfcatch))>
```

Although when you dump it, the `cfcatch` data looks like a ColdFusion struct it isn't really, the `duplicate` forces it to a ColdFusion struct which it can then serialize. Be aware that duplicate does a deep copy.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630495/291653 for more info about what cfcatch is.